# I am trying to create a dictionary of characters that I read in from a text file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I can read an entire string but it doesn't count the individual chars.

Here is what I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

ans = True

while ans:
    print("""
    1. Read in an text file.

    Press enter to exit
    """)

    ans=raw_input("Make a selection")

    if ans == "1":

        print("Enter in a text file to open")
        txt = raw_input("> ")
        txt_open = open(txt, 'r')

        d = dict()
        for c in txt_open:
            if c not in d:
                d[c] = 1
            else:
                d[c] += 1

        print d
```

Comment: Can you please show what the input is like, and what is the expected output?

Comment: A dictionary is a mapping from keys to values. You can't just have a dictionary of some kind of value, without saying what you want to map it to.

Comment: Anyway, it sounds like you're trying to build something just like [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). Why not just use that? (Or, if you want to know how it works, look at [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/collections.py#l387)—that's why the docs page has a link to it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a file is an iterable of *lines*, not *characters*. So, in this:

```
for c in txt_open:
```

Each `c` is a whole line. If you want each characters in the line, add another loop:

```
for line in txt_open:
    for c in line:
```

Alternatively, if you want to, you can `read` the whole file into one big string and loop over its characters (but keep in mind that this means you need to fit the whole file into memory, and you need to read the whole file before you can process any of it):

```
for c in txt_open.read():
```

---

In the future, when you have problems like this, the first step should be looking at the values you get. You can use the debugger, or a live visualizer, or you can just add `print` statements into your code. For example, if you `print` each `c`, it'll immediately be obvious what's wrong.

---

Meanwhile, what you're building already exists in the stdlib as [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), so you can just use it:

```
d = collections.Counter()
for line in txt_open:
    for c in line:
        d[c] += 1
```

… or, more simply:

```
d = collections.Counter()
for line in txt_open:
    d.update(line)
```

… or, even *more* simply:

```
d = collections.Counter(c for line in txt_open for c in line)
```

… or, if you prefer:

```
d = collections.Counter(txt_open.read())
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The extra for loop fixed my problem. I am new to python. I removed all my print statements and checks to make the code as small as possible. Guess I will leave them in in the future.

Comment: @will3: Once you know it's all working, or you've gotten as much information out of them as you're going to, take out the `print`s. (And if you needed some of that information to help debug the problem, post what you learned as part of your SO question. If you say "I put in a `print c` right after the `for` loop, and each one was a bunch of characters, maybe a whole line", people will know what you've already figured out and what you haven't, and can usually help you solve the problem faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict_ = collections.defaultdict(int)

with open(filename, 'r') as file_:
   for line in file_:
      for character in line:
         dict_[character] += 1
```

HTH

Comment: I can't imagine any circumstance where you couldn't use `Counter` but could use `defaultdict` to try to build a `Counter` manually…

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another for-loop for every line to reach each character:

```
for line in txt_open:
    for c in line:
        if c not in d:
            d[c] = 1
        else:
            d[c] += 1

print d
```